# Odd default formatting on Button?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can anyone tell me why this (the circled part) is happening? This happened immediately after I added it to the activity.

[image]

The all important (and relevant) part of the xml:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Delivery Approval" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/CornflowerBlue"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Quantity Approved?"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                style="@style/subText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Is the quantity being delivered correct and all accounted for?"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                    style="@style/subRadioButtons"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/quaYes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="Yes" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/quaNo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="No" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/CornflowerBlue"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Condition Approved?"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Is the condition of delivery satisfactory?"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/subText"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
                    style="@style/subRadioButtons"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/conYes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="Yes" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/conNo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="No" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/CornflowerBlue"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Proof"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="If delivery has not been approved. Please provide proof. Using either Photographic evidence, or voice, detailing issue."
                    android:textAppearance="@style/subText"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="128dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_photo" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="128dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_record" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmdNext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Customer Signature"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I've set `textAlignment` to center, but it does nothing. Is this an issue with using a Table layout maybe? Possibly, due to other layouts in the activity, it's being forced over one side?

**Edit #1** - Posted entire XML file, as it stands currently.

**Edit #2** - Have tried running on the device, but still the same formatting issue, so it's definitely somewhere in my XML, maybe an inherited property (which I tend to avoid, for exactly this reason). I've also attempted to set the position of the text to **any** other position and nothing changes in the designer, nor on the device/emulator.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try adding `android:gravity="center"` to the Button. Maybe your theme is setting gravity to right.

Comment: 'fraid not. Just tried. No difference :(

Comment: Have you tried testing it on a device? Sometimes the generated layout is a bit wonky.

Comment: Wait, don't you need to be escaping those `>` characters? That could be making it go wonky in the editor.

Comment: @Tenfour04 - Nah, thought of that and took them out. No change. :) Am attempting a test on device now.

Comment: I'm guessing the part of the XML you posted works fine when it's on its own... What's root ViewGroup of your layout? Might as well post the whole XML.

Comment: Yeah, I've ripped this XML apart attempting to recreate it with minimal interference, but it only shifts right when on the activity as a whole. Have posted entire XML. Should've done that to begin with...

Comment: @EmbattledSwag - Device shows the same behaviour as the designer does. It's annoying me now. No matter what styling property I change, nothing sets the text back to center, nor any other position for that matter.

Comment: Try cleaning your project via Project/Clean. I've just tried the XML and it's all fine for me. I've had to remove the styles since I don't have access to them. I think it's either a build bug OR you have some kind of theme/style affecting all buttons that we cannot see. Check your AndroidManifest for themes, etc.

Comment: It's got to be the style or theme on the activity setting some property on the button (or TextViews, which Buttons inherit from).

Comment: After days of it showing off-center. It finally stopped. I have no idea why, I've been on a different activity since this as I was getting no where. Must've been some odd Eclipse thing that I've just not seen before. I copied the entire XML into a separate project and it worked fine. *shrugs* Cheers all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one (however, I couldn't test it so I am not sure)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Delivery Approval"
            android:gravity="left" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/CornflowerBlue"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Quantity Approved?"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                style="@style/subText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Is the quantity being delivered correct and all accounted for?"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                    style="@style/subRadioButtons"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/quaYes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="Yes" />
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/quaNo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="No" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/CornflowerBlue"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Condition Approved?"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Is the condition of delivery satisfactory?"
                android:textAppearance="@style/subText"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
                    style="@style/subRadioButtons"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/conYes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="Yes" />
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/conNo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="No" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/CornflowerBlue"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Proof"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="If delivery has not been approved. Please provide proof. Using either Photographic evidence, or voice, detailing issue."
                    android:textAppearance="@style/subText"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="128dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_photo" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="128dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_record" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmdNext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Customer Signature"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```